# content type inside another content type in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I need to maintain Projects as List Items in SharePoint Online List. I tried **Task List** which is **built-in app**. But After i create **Sub Task** for the Task, it is still able to make it as **Task(one level higher)** using Indent which is under the Tasks Menu. By making this my purpose is getting diluted.

Are you getting me?

Obviously, Items in the list is based on the content type. So, i thought of creating subTasks also based on content Type. Since, i'm not sure is that possible to create **content type inside another content type**. Please suggest me in this regard. In addition to that i need Time line feature as in **Task List(build-in app)** in SharePoint Online.

Or

Is there any other solution to maintain the Projects (Tasks) and maintain its stages as subTask? and I also need to make flow of sub task one after the other(waterfall model).

Saw child content type. Will it be feasible to achieve the above goal? The related comments will be really appreciated.